# ActionBar options

Tags: android

I have just managed to put actionbar tab menu into my application now i have 5 tabs which are mostly important in application, now i want to put "Options" icon in action bar where user will have access to options and few other forms. If someone can help me with any code examples as i tryed with developer.android.com but i didnt suceedd.

Here is example of what i am looking for:

[image]

Tabs are already done now i want to implement this (3 dots last icon on the right) as options menu.

Comment: Did you read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems ? I think it's well described there.

Comment: Yup i know but i dont know what i am doing wrong i just try like it is on this site but my app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Add your extra action to the menu with android:showAsAction="never":

```
<!-- Settings should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
```

But still, the overflow button (icon with three dots) will only appear if your device does not have a hardware menu button. Here 'menu' will bring the additional actions. On a device with no hardware buttons, the overflow button will be shown.

You may see the difference by setting up different AVDs.

(Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems)